# What is pointer to string in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I need to understand what is a pointer to string, I mean for example:

```
char *str[]
```

We can find this in the main parameters:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

So that the second parameter is an a pointer to string & I want to know what that means in C.

Comment: This is pretty standard. I suggest you read Kernighan & Ritchie "C Programming Language".

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking here. What do you want to know?

Comment: They want to know what pointers are.

Comment: `char *str[]` as a function argument is a pointer to pointer to `char` (`char **str`).

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array of pointers pointing to zero terminated c-strings.

I painted the following pretty picture to help you visualize something about the pointers.

[image]

And here is a code example that shows you how an operating system would pass arguments to your executable. You can call your executable via command line and add any number of additional arguments separated with spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mainLookalike(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0: printf("application name is: %s\n", argv[i]); break;
            default:  printf("argument %i is: %s\n", i, argv[i]); break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    printf("arguments taken from main\n");
    mainLookalike(argc, argv);
    printf("\n");
    printf("created my own arguments\n");
    char * app = "MyApplication.exe";
    char arg1[] = "argonaut";
    char * arg2 = "widgeteer";

    char * myargv[] = {app, arg1, arg2};
    int myargc = sizeof(myargv) / sizeof(char*);
    mainLookalike(myargc, myargv);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `char` is a type for storing a single character.
- `char*` is a pointer to a memory location. This memory location could be anything. At minimal the memory location contains a single character but it could also be a character array (thus a string).
- `char* []` is an array of `char*` thus an array containing multiple pointers to memory locations where character array's are stored. In other words `char* []` is  an array of strings or a two-dimensional array of characters.

Please note that `C` is not a managed programming language. 
You are pretty loose in how to store data. A pointer itself doesn't mean much. Often the documentation of a particular library will till you what you may expect.

Answer (score 0):

`char* []` or `char **` is two-dimensional array of characters. String is array of characters but vice versa does not always true cos string is array of characters that contain `NU**L**`(or `'\0'` character not `NU**LL**` at some where).

Ex:

```
char arr1[] = {'a', 'b', '\0', 'd'};
char arr2[] = {'d'};
char *test[] = {arr1, arr2};

printf("%s\n", test[0]);
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("'%c' ", test[0][i]);
```

In this example, first output will be `ab`, second output will be `'a' 'b' '' 'd'`

Answer (score -2):

The main signature is also :

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
```

so basically, it's an array of strings. It contains line argument, you can acess to the data this way:

```
argv[0] 
argv[1]
argv[2]
...
```

In C, a string is simply a arrays of char or a pointer to a char. So an array of string is also an array of arrays of char.